# How to convert PPTX to PDF via the COM class?

Tags: php, pdf, com, powerpoint

I have a little problem with converte PPTX to PDF with the COM class. PowerPoint opens but cannot convert to pdf with the ExportAsFixedFormat function, telling me that parameter 0 is the wrong type. But, my path is a string and the function needs a string so i'm confused ?

Can you help me pls, I just want convert a PPTX in PDF :'( ?

The error :

```
com_exception: Parameter 0: Le type ne correspond pas. in C:\wamp64\www\TP1\pt_legrand\php\demarrage_controle.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\TP1\pt_legrand\php\demarrage_controle.php(13): variant->ExportAsFixedFormat2('C://wamp64//www...', 32) #1 C:\wamp64\www\TP1\pt_legrand\php\texte.inc.php(24): include_once('C:\\wamp64\\www\\T...') #2 C:\wamp64\www\TP1\pt_legrand\index.php(8): require_once('C:\\wamp64\\www\\T...') #3 {main}
```

My code :

```
        try{
        $pp = new COM("Powerpoint.Application") or die ("Could not initialise Object.");
        $pp->Visible = true;
        // open the pp 2007-2013 document 
        $pp->Presentations->Open('C://wamp64//www//TP1//pt_legrand//php//test.pptx');
        // convert pp 2007-2013 to PDF
        $filePath = 'C://wamp64//www//TP1//pt_legrand//php';
        $pp->ActivePresentation->ExportAsFixedFormat2(
            $filePath,
            2
        );
        $pp->Quit(false);
        // clean up
        unset($pp);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps not the main issue (not a PHP person), but why are you referring to PowerPoint as Word? `WdExportCreateBookmarks` is from Word... but in any case that `32` should probably be `2`, corresponding to `ppFixedFormatTypePDF`.

Comment: Yeah it's some copy and paste and some bad smell code '^^. I try with 2 but already the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you could try [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.saveas) method. Honestly, that type mismatch error is quite unobvious.

```
$pp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs('THE_PATH/file.pdf', 32);
```

Comment: I was just working with this in VBA, where you must:  1) supply a path separator after .Path, 2) supply the name of the PDF to export, not just the path, and 3) supply an Intent parameter after the export type parameter. For print you'd supply 2.  I guess the requirements would be the same for any other language.

Comment: I think, the problem is that for some reason PowerPoint _ExportAsFixedFormat_ method throws `Parameter 0: type mismatch` exception regardless of parameters, while related Word and Excel methods works as expected (PHP). So, it doesn't even check specified path itself. A side note: you need to pass the full absolute path for both source and converted files `realpath("related_path/file.ext")` and may also convert this string to Windows-1251 `iconv("UTF-8", "CP1251//IGNORE", realpath("related_path/file.ext"))` to prevent problems with Unicode